# Does crossbar need to be flush against junction box?

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, mounting, junction-box

I have a question regarding installing a chandelier light fixture in my apartment. The light fixture I bought came with a standard crossbar and I originally screwed it flush into the junction box. However, in doing so, the crossbar became too deep and the I couldn't attach the canopy. To remedy this issue, I basically unscrewed the crossbar about halfway to accommodate the depth so that the canopy would screw tight. My question is if this is safe...does the crossbar need to be tightly attached to the junction box or can it be tightened halfway as I'm describing? I pulled on the crossbar lightly to see if it would hold and it seemed to be fine, but I want to be sure this is safe.

Comment: Personally I would find a way to make the screws tight. Loose screws never get tighter only looser. Either shim the bracket or use a lock nut.  One of the electric experts here may come along with a better idea.

Comment: I'm not a licensed electrician, but I have a hunch @PlatinumGoose is absolutely correct. I know of nothing which requires the crossbar to be "tightly" attached, but it must be securely attached for sure. Look on Amazon or your local electric supply store (not a box box like Lowes), bring your crossbar and a photo. There are flat crossbar strips, ones angled outwards in hump, and adjustable/extensible crossbars. I suspect that all you need is some lock nuts or some kind of spacer. Over time vibrations could cause things to loosen, and if the lamp swings out it could damage the wires.